# Help&Manual. В chm не открывается сайт через кнопку Help Windows

Tags: документация, chm

Работаю в Help&Manual. В Configuration->Common properties->Help windows задаю кнопке Home ссылку на сайт (условно https://www.google.com). Ссылка без якоря. В chm файле падает ошибка:

```
Убедитесь, что веб-адрес mk:@MSITStore:E:\SVN\Helps\projectfolder\_output\projectname.chm::/https://www.google.com правильный
```

Причём в другом проекте ошибка не падает. Не смог понять в чём причина. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать.